# Python: Read CSV file select columns and create multiple text file

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, text

I have a CSV file with 2 columns `ID` and `Info`. I want to create multiple text files. 
Get the `ID` column as the filename and the `Info` column as the file content.

My csv file:

```
ID          Info
an_0000     No-19032745 2.20s 
an_0001     No-42037578 2.54s 
an_0002     No-56034123 6.71s
an_0003     No-87036247 1.91s
an_0004     No-13032757 1.15s
an_0005     No-44032657 1.91s
an_0006     No-14038488 5.11s
an_0007     No-19039678 1.20s
an_0008     No-53031654 2.50s
```

The filename i want:

```
an_0000.txt
...
```

The file content i want:

```
No-19032745 2.20s 
...
```

Comment: Did you tried anything to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
for filename, content in zip(df['ID'],df['Info']):
    with open(filename+".txt",'w') as fp:
        fp.write(content)
```